# FFMPEG concat does not include a looped image (using named pipes)

Tags: mac, bash, video, ffmpeg

After a lot of research and testing, I wrote a command that I can adapt for multiple sources to be concatenated using FFMPEG. I'm running into a problem though with add looped images (as videos) into the concatenation.

Here's the command:

```
ffmpeg -y -i input1.mp4 -c copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts temp1 2> /dev/null & \
ffmpeg -y -i input2.mp4 -c copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts temp2 2> /dev/null & \
ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i anullsrc  -loop 1 -f image2 -i input3.jpg -r 30 -t 3 -pix_fmt yuvj420p -map 0:a -map 1:v -f mpegts temp3 2> /dev/null & \
ffmpeg -y -f mpegts -i "concat:temp1|temp2|temp3" -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc out.mp4
```

The end result should be 2 videos, then an image looped for 3 seconds (with no audio), all concatenated into a long video. Instead, all I get is a single concatenated video that contains the first two videos, but not the image looped.

Comment: Here's the output from FFMPEG: http://d.pr/n/1aHGB

Comment: Please show the complete console output of: `ffmpeg -i input1.mp4 -i input2.mp4 -i input3.jpg`

Comment: @LordNeckbeard what do you hope for with that command? It's only inputs - do you mean ffmpeg concat with those inputs?

Comment: I want to see all of the info about the inputs. I suspect they need some work before being concatenated.

Comment: Ah ok. Here's the output: http://d.pr/n/19Dgv

Comment: Does it matter the size of the videos/image? They're all different sizes. Maybe I should scale to the same width/height?

Comment: You will need to match the parameters between all inputs, so you will need to scale/pad/crop to a common size, use format filter to make the same pixel format, fps filter for same frame rate, anullsrc filter to make a silent audio, setpts to set timestamps to 0, and finally concat filter to concatenate. There are probably a dozen examples on SU, but I'm too busy right now to find them.

Answer (score 0):

It appears your script backgrounds the first 3 commands, so your script runs the commands at virtually the same time. There is no guarantee commands 1-3 will complete before the 4th concatenates their output. Removing trailing ampersands and backslashes will cause the script to wait for each command to complete before starting the next. If each command uses most of the i/o bandwidth, then this change will not slow your script much. Otherwise, here is a method to run the first 3 commands in the background but to wait until they're done to run the 4th (untested).

```
{ ./prog1 ; ./prog2 ; ./prog3 ; } && ./prog4
```

Comment: I'm actually closely following FFMPEG's Concatenate documentation, so I don't know that it should be written like you suggested... Also your proposed solution would require writing scripts for each command.

Comment: I did not intend to suggest that more 'progs' would be necessary. "prog1", for example, is a placeholder for "ffmpeg -y -i input1.mp4 -c copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts temp1". (You would /not/ need to make more commands.) My overall point was to explore the job control inherent in bash, e.g. backgrounding jobs and its implications. I don't have the ffmpeg docs, but I do think that if you try the code snippet (of course inserting your ffmpeg commands in full instead of "prog1", e.g.) you may be pleasantly surprised. Good luck to you.